# Disable screen blank from bash to customize live ISO

Tags: 18.04, live-usb, system-settings

Is it possible to disable screen blank feature from bash?

I am on Ubuntu 18 and trying to set up an Ubuntu 18 (Gnome) live system with some preconfigurations. One of them is to not let the screen go dark and lock the session. I am using Cubic to preinstall some software on the live system and to change some settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the idle trim feature with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false
```

Screen wont get dark then black and wont lock

Comment: do I have to run this command after startup or will it be a permanent setting?

Comment: Tried your command as normal user and sudo. The screen still turns off and locks after the time period set in system settings.

Answer (score 0):

To make this permanent, you need a gsettings override file...

1. Open a new empty document in gedit (or other text editor) on your host system.
2. Add the following contents to your file:

   ```
   [org.gnome.desktop.screensaver]
   lock-enabled = false

   [org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power]
   idle-dim = false
   ```
3. Save the file with the following name:

   ```
   90_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override
   ```
4. In Cubic's terminal page, type the following command and press the enter key.

   ```
   cd /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   ```
5. Open Nautilus (or other file browser) on your host system, and naviage to the directory where you saved the file `90_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override`.
6. Drag the file onto Cubic's terminal window.
7. Click the <kbd>Copy</kbd> button in Cubic.
8. The file will be copied to the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` directory inside Cubic.
9. Then type the following command inside Cubic's terminal window.

   ```
   glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   ```
10. Finish making your other customizations, and generate your new Live ISO using Cubic.

Whenever you bootup or install your OS from the new Live ISO, Ubuntu will read default gsettings values from `90_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override`.

If you add other settings to `90_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override`, remember to execute the `glib-compile-schemas` command each time.

As you may expect, the user can always personalize your defaults using tools like Gnome Tweaks, Dconf Editor or the `gsettings` command.

Answer (score 0):

I have done all this and I hope it works ... I will post if it does.
"
I will add for others unfamiliar with "His" program "Cubits" ...

it can all be done with a file manager.